# How To Restrict Transaction between states in azure devops server?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, workitem, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I am decided to restrict transaction between two states in azure devops server in inherited process
but i donot know support or not?
if support , how to do it?
i read [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops) but not found in my azure devops web admin

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this [release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-172-update) has not been updated to the azure devops server.  I also did not find the "Restrict the transaction to state" in the Actions on my side.

[image]

The release of this feature is currently only for azure devops service. For the release note of Azure DevOps Server, please follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019u1?view=azure-devops).